# How to deal with HTML entities in Rails to_json output?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I'm writing an app that uses Rails on the backend and javascript/backbone on the frontend.  I'm trying to [bootstrap some rails models into my javascript](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset). Specifically, I'd like to load the contents of `@courses` into a js variable called `window.courses`. I've got the following in an `html.erb` file.

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
    window.courses = JSON.parse('<%= @courses.to_json %>');
<% end %>
```

I'm expecting the `erb` preprocessor to render this into valid javascript, like so

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    window.courses = JSON.parse('[{"code":"myCourseCode", ...
//]]>
</script>
```

... but, instead, I'm getting code that includes [HTML entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    window.courses = JSON.parse('[{&quot;code&quot;:&quot;myCourseCode&quot;, ...
//]]>
</script>
```

Obviously, I get javascript errors when I try to parse this.

Does anyone know how I can deal with these HTML entities in order to produce valid javascript?  I realize that one option would be to [unescape the entities on the client side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1912546/765287), but this seems like a roundabout solution.  Is there a way that I can get Rails to produce JSON that doesn't need unescaping?

Comment: Try using `<%= raw(@courses.to_json) %>`

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I figured there must be a simple way to do this.

Comment: @dB' would you consider updating the accepted answer? this is very unsafe and has been the source of many cross-site scripting vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you intend to use raw(obj.to_json) you MUST ensure the following is set.

```
ActiveSupport.escape_html_entities_in_json = true
```

Answer (score 5):

The question is solved by my comment, just for the record:

Rails escapes strings that are printed using `<%= 'string' %>`. By this, it is save to ouput user data.
So, if you don't want Rails to escape the output, you have to tell Rails explicitly by using `raw('string')`.

In your code, that would be:
`<%= raw(@courses.to_json) %>`

Comment: this is basically asking for xss. trivially. I've seen this hundreds of times, please don't ever use raw.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @oreoshake. Can you please point me a direction to an alternative?

Comment: In the answer above, I mention `ActiveSupport.escape_html_entities_in_json = true`. With that setting, and the default json backends, using <= @courses.to_json.html_safe %> is safe from xss.